# Connecting Sybase and running SQL from Solaris

Tags: sql, solaris, sybase

I want to connect from a Solaris environment to a remote Sybase server (I have the IP and user credential to connect) and run some SQL queries. What existing apps/scripts can I use?

Comment: You need the Sybase client - isql and libraries see the Sybase site or ask your System Aministrator

Comment: as far as I tested isql is not accepting connection to remote server,right?

Comment: `isql` runs on your local system, and connects to the remote database, but you must use a servername, and not an IP address to connect.  Vince's answer should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about Sybase ASE server (I am not sure for SQLAnywhere) you local isql can access to a remote ASE server. In your Sybase client home, add the following in your 'interfaces' file in replacing hostname and ASE_port_number:

```
ASE_SERVER
    master tcp ether <hostname> <ASE_port_number>
    query tcp ether <hostname> <ASE_port_number>
```

example:

```
ASE_TEST_A
    master tcp ether server1 5200
    query tcp ether server1 5200
```

then run ISQL:
`isql -U sa -S ASE_TEST_A -P password -w200`

Comment: You can also use `dsedit` and `dscp` to edit the interfaces file instead of manually editing it.

Comment: database is Sybase IQ,applicable?

Comment: I test it is working fine, thanks, another question: isql is Interactive, is there a way to put it in a bash script ?

Comment: actualy, I was trying to use DBI and ODBC of perl for connection but seems ODBC is not installed on our system and I cannot convince Admin to install it, so is there a way still to use perl without ODBC ? or any other scripting language?

Comment: Michael Peppler developed a Perl module DBD::Sybase to connect to Sybase ASE. You could check if it works for IQ as well. I also think that the Sybase ASE client 15.7 includes modules to connect to ASE via Perl.